# Why cookies are added rather than changed?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I am developing a site where each user should have their own id. When I went into the console, I saw that the id was duplicated instead of being one. Is this normal and should it be?

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['SESSION']) && (strlen($_COOKIE['SESSION']) === 32)) {
    $uid = $_COOKIE['SESSION'];
} else {
    $uid = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $uid = bin2hex($uid);
}
setcookie("SESSION", $uid, time()+(60*60*24*30));
$uid=$_COOKIE['SESSION'];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies, by default, use the path of the page that they are set for.

You should explicitly set the path to `/` using the 4th argument to [`setcookie`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

---

Aside: PHP has [built-in session handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). You probably shouldn't be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: setcookie("SESSION", $uid, time()+(60*60*24*30), "/"); - Thats right?